# another regex which does the same as "diff.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n "

Tags: ruby, regex, perl

I have this regex:

```
diff.\*\n.\*\n.\*\n.\*\n.\*\n
```

I want to match everything from the word "diff" to the fifth new line. Can someone simplify it for me?

Comment: sorry, i'll edit the question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need grouping:

```
 diff(?:.*\n){5}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for this:

```
/diff(.*\n){5}/
```